# Fluture bimap and fold, what is the difference and when should I use them?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, future, fluture

### Background

I am using [Fluture](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture) to abstract Futures.

Let's say I have a function that makes a GET request. This function can succeed or fail.

Upon making a request, if it succeeds, it prints a message, if it fails, it logs the error and executes a command.

```
axios.get(endpoint, { timeout: timeoutMs })
    .fold(
        err =>
            logger.errorAsync( err )
            .chain( ( ) => cmd.getAsync("pm2 restart app")),
        response => logger.infoAsync( "Great success!" )
    );
```

### Research

I have been reading the API, and I found that `bimap` and `fold` both apply a function to success and error:

**bimap**: Maps the left function over the rejection value, or the right function over the resolution value, depending on which is present.

**fold**: Applies the left function to the rejection value, or the right function to the resolution value, depending on which is present, and resolves with the result.

### Problem

If you have a keen eye, you will know my example *doesn't* work. I need to use `bimap`, but I don't get why.

### Questions

1. When should I use `bimap` and when should I use `fold`?
2. What are the main differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first examine their respective type signatures:

```
bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> Future a b -> Future c d
fold  :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Future a b -> Future d c
```

The difference is quite subtle, but visible. There are two major differences:

1. The return value of the second argument is different: In `bimap`, both
   functions are allowed to return different types. In `fold`, both functions
   must return a value of the same type.
2. The final return value is different: In `bimap`, you get back a Future where
   the rejection contains a value of the type returned from the left function,
   and the resolution contains a value of the type returned from the right
   function. In `fold`, the rejection side contains a whole new type variable that
   is yet to be restricted, and the resolution side contains a value of the
   type returned by *both* function.

That's a quite a mouthful, and possibly a bit difficult to parse. I'll try to visualize it in diagrams.

For `bimap`, it looks like the following. The two branches don't interact:

```
             rej(x)  res(y)
                 |       |
                 |       |
bimap(f)(g):   f(x)    g(y)
                 |       |
                 V       V
```

For `fold`, the rejection branch kind of "stops", and the resoltion branch will
continue with the return value from `f(x)` *or* the return value from `g(y)`:

```
             rej(x)  res(y)
                 |       |
                 |       |
fold(f)(g):      ->  f(x)*g(y)
                         |
                         V
```

---

You can use `bimap` whenever you'd like to change the rejection reason and the
resolution value at the same time. Doing `bimap (f) (g)` is like doing
`compose (mapRej (f)) (map (g))`.

You can use `fold` whenever you want to move your rejection into the resolution
branch. In your case, this is what you want. The reason your example doesn't
work is because you end up with a Future of a Future, which you have to
flatten:

```
axios.get(endpoint, { timeout: timeoutMs })
    .fold(
        err =>
            logger.errorAsync( err )
            .chain( ( ) => cmd.getAsync("pm2 restart app")),
        response => logger.infoAsync( "Great success!" )
    )
    .chain(inner => inner); //<-- Flatten
```

Flattening a Monad is very common in Functional Programming, and is typically
called `join`, which can be implemented like:

```
const join = chain(x => x)
```

Answer (score 1):

One might use `bimap` to both map *rejection* and *resolution* in a single step, and the `Future` will remain *rejected* or *resolved* with a new computation.

In the other hand, `fold`will handle both *rejection* and *resolution*  to always produce a *resolution* (you're folding both cases into the *resolution* one). One would use `fold` to either wrap both results into another type (for example `Future Either a b`) or to treat any branch as *successful*.

Thus, `bimap` differs from `fold` because the first maps both cases and the second turns either case into a *resolution*.

### Sample: `bimap`:

```
const flag = true
const eventualNumber1 = !flag ? Future.reject (1) : Future.of (2)
const eventualNumber2 = Future.bimap (x => x * 2) (x => x + 1) (eventualNumber1)

// it'll output 3. 
Future.fork (console.log) (console.log) (eventualNumber2)
```

### Sample: `fold`:

```
const flag = false
const eventualNumber1 = !flag ? Future.reject (1) : Future.of (2)
const eventualNumber2 = Future.fold (x => x * 2) (x => x + 1) (eventualNumber1)

// It'll output 2 even when the Future represents a rejection
Future.value (console.log) (eventualNumber2)
```

Note how `fold` gives me the full guarantee that `eventualNumber2` is a *resolution*, so I use `Future.value` which only handle resolutions!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Do you really think that your edit is fine? You changed some identifiers based on your own coding style. If I could, I would downvote your edit.

Comment: Not based on my coding style. Your previous code was incorrect because `eventualNumber1` was never being used anywhere. I merely tried to fix what I perceived was a simple mistake from your part. If however, my fix was incorrect, please feel free to let me know and I will gladly revert it back to it's original glory. No need to be offended :P

Comment: There, I have re-edited my edit so it stays more consistent with your original version _and still works_.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I see, I see. I missed giving `eventualNumber1`. Anyway see how I've re-edited the answer myself: my approach is using static functions.

Comment: An approach as respectable as any other. Happy to know that future passengers can now benefit from the correctness of your answer as well.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Absolutely. I'd say that you should suggest corrections instead of directly editing answers, because maybe you can't capture the background behind the reasoning of the answerer. Anyway, no problem :D